# What is the use of concatenating -D and -P ex -DargName=argVal and -PargName=argValue?

Tags: java, shell, maven, command-line-arguments

I searched a lot for this but I didn't find any proper answer.

I have seen this many times while passing command line arguments for maven and ant.

The arguments are passed either by concatenating it with -D or -P

eg:
mvn -Pcargo.run -Drepo.path=storage

how does -D and -P defer? and are they confined to specific technology?

any help will be appreciated.
Thanks!

Comment: `-P` is to activate/deactivate profiles whereas `-D..` defines system properties...

Comment: @khmarbaise thanks! ..just one last question are they specific to java?

Comment: Yes cause Maven is a Build Tool primarly for Java...